# How to return a class from array.Map with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How do I make the bottom statement return an array of StoreModels? The signatures of model and store match between the interface and the mapped array.

```
interface StoreModels {
    model: string | undefined;
    store: string;
}

const proposedStoreValues = proposedStores.map(({ model, store }) => ({ model, store }));
```

Comment: Do you want to make proposedStoreValues to has type of array of StoreModels ? maybe this signature solve: `({ model, store }): StoreModels => ({ model, store })`

Comment: That's it, thank you.  If you post as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As see in comments, you need just add the signature of `StoreModels` in the arrow function:

```
interface StoreModels {
    model: string | undefined;
    store: string;
}

const proposedStoreValues = proposedStores.map(({ model, store }): StoreModels => ({ model, store }));
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
const proposedStoreValues = proposedStores.map(
  ({model, store}: StoreModels) => ({
    model,
    store
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the return type to a arrow function like this: `(): ReturnVal => something`